# Average of a player

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, average, ssms-2017

[image]I have a record that contains stat for a certain cricket player.
It has columns having dates, oppositions, Runs, Balls, Dismissals, Match_Number.
I want to do a query (SQL SERVER) to find out the batting average where every runs (Sum) is to be added; innings having a count of all innings except DNB but dismissal should not have a count of  "Not Out", "Retired Hurt", "DNB" grouped by the opposition.

Note : DNB means Did not Bat.
[The query doesn't have the required number of innings to calculate the average](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCESd.png)

So the problem is can't gather information for a single entity (count of no. of innings) having two set of parameters.

1. Without DNB
2. Without DNB, Not Out, Retired Hurt.

Please suggest.

Comment: *Consumable* sample data, expected results, and your attempts will all greatly help us help you. We don't have enough information as it stands.

Comment: table schema, sample data and desired results will help, see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please add sample code and sample DB structure.

Comment: For Example: schema name dbo.SRTendulkarODI, containing 462 data record. Required column name Opposition, Innings, Total runs, Average.

Comment: Problem Statement: by self-join, I cannot yield the required number of innings as the requirement is two sets of data for runs and innings. Any other suggestions....

Answer (score 0):

You can put a case expression within an aggregate to exclude certain rows from a count/sum/average etc. So you could use something like this:

```
SELECT a.Opposition,
        Matches = COUNT(*),
        Innings = COUNT(CASE WHEN a.Dismissal <> 'DNB' THEN 1 END),
        Runs = SUM(a.Runs),
        Average = SUM(a.Runs) / NULLIF(COUNT(CASE WHEN a.Dismissal NOT IN ('DNB', 'Not Out', 'Retired not out') THEN 1 END), 0)
FROM    dbo.SRTundlkarODI AS a
GROUP BY a.Opposition;
```

N.B. I have wrapped the `COUNT` for the average in `NULLIF(<exp>, 0)` so that should the batsmen have never got out you avoid a divide by zero error.

Comment: Well, that helped.